# How to tell the TCP server that the particular message has ended?

Tags: sockets, networking, tcp, network-programming, network-protocols

TCP client sends data byte by byte. So, how to tell the server that this message has ended and the new message begins now?

One way is to fix a special character that'll be sent as a bookmark, but that character can also be a part of the message causing confusions.

Any other optimum way out?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the message is binary, delimited encoding using a special character is not possible. Tag Length Value (TLV) encoding will be best suited for this.

for example

```
 +--------+----------+----------------+    
 |  Tag   | Length   |  Content       |    
 | 0x0001 |  0x000C  | "HELLO, WORLD" |    
 +--------+----------+----------------+
```

in addition to that, you can have more than one message type

Comment: How to tell TCP server (in the second message) that tag value is for new message not a part of the old one.

Comment: that should be handled by your program's state. you can have sequence number as an additional parameter to explicitly mark this is 1st, that is 2nd. but is not necessary for TCP based apps. If you are designing application level protocol, I recommend you to read Principles of Protocol Design by Robin Sharp :).

Comment: You are missing the point perhaps. Example message:`2222222` Here, the first two 2's are the part of first message, second 2 is the sequence number, remaining 2's are a part of the second message. How according to your answer should server make out which 2 is the sequence numebr?

Comment: that has to be defined in your frame format, and number of read bytes has to be counted and a state should be maintained, for example https://gist.github.com/1582634 .

Comment: I get your point now. Thanks. Lot of work to be done by the server. :)

Comment: Also, it will make more sense if you add this factor to your answer.

Answer (score 2):

One possible way can be that before sending the actual message you can send the number of bytes in the particular message. When the receiving side has received that number of bytes it can start receiving next message

Comment: number of bytes can be a number in the message too, how will server know that message has ended or started?

Comment: what I have been doing is to add a pseudo header to the message. The first four bytes let us say of any message will tell us that how many bytes after it correspond to the message  TCPHeader -> PseudoHeader1 ->Message1 ->PsuedoHeader2->Message2

Comment: IMHO this is the best way to do this from a consumer's perspective, be that a server or a client of your protocol. With a length prefixed message you know how much data to read to start with, sizeof(length prefix), and once you get the length you then know the exact size of the message. This makes it very efficient to parse messages. The alternative is a message terminator character which requires the consumer to scan the entire message for the terminator. I talk about length prefixed messages here: http://bit.ly/zzk76e (sorry about the shortened link, the real one is too long for the comment)

Comment: Raza and @LenHolgate My point was that in second message how will TCP know that X is the PseudoHeader not the message body?

Comment: you will have to implement your state machine in such a way that you can differentiate between the two. For every received message, first read the pseudo header and then read the message body.  you will have to take care of some error conditions as well.

Comment: Anisha, the point is that TCP doesn't know or care. TCP deals in terms of a stream of bytes; everything else is your problem.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the implementation used in [networkComms.net](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net/), the open source communication framework. In particular IncomingPacketHandleHandOff() on line 892 [here](https://bitbucket.org/MarcF/networkcomms.net/src/31c498a2ff28/NetworkCommsDotNet/Connection.cs#cl-892).

It guarantees that the first byte received specifies the size of a packet header (Less than 255 bytes). Once enough bytes have been received in order to rebuild the header, the header can be inspected to determine remaining size to be received (data section). If you have more incoming bytes than the expected header and data sections you look at the very first byte and start over.

Using bookmarked characters is what is used at the base level of the network stack but must be implemented carefully to avoid further complications.

Answer (score 1):

If you wish to use a character as both the end of message marker or as a part of the message, you need to use an escape sequence.

For example: Use the character '$' to end the message, and '%' to escape

i.e.

```
%$ -> $
%% -> %
```

then use '$' to end the message

All alternatively send the number of bytes to be received at the start of the messssage (or message chunk if you do not know the lenght of the complete message at that point).

Comment: In second message how will TCP know that % is the escape character not the message body? Same to the number of bytes too.